# How to calculate distances between points along a path

Tags: r, gis, r-sf

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.8.0, GDAL 3.0.4, PROJ 6.3.1
```

I have some data where I would like to calculate the distances between each point (station) along defined paths.

```r
dat <-
  structure(
    list(
      name = c(
        "Untitled Path",
        "St34B",
        "St35N",
        "St36F",
        "St37N",
        "St38B",
        "Untitled Path",
        "St39N"
      ),
      description = c(
        NA_character_,
        NA_character_,
        NA_character_,
        NA_character_,
        NA_character_,
        NA_character_,
        NA_character_,
        NA_character_
      ),
      timestamp = structure(
        c(
          NA_real_,
          NA_real_,
          NA_real_,
          NA_real_,
          NA_real_,
          NA_real_,
          NA_real_,
          NA_real_
        ),
        class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"),
        tzone = ""
      ),
      begin = structure(
        c(
          NA_real_,
          NA_real_,
          NA_real_,
          NA_real_,
          NA_real_,
          NA_real_,
          NA_real_,
          NA_real_
        ),
        class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"),
        tzone = ""
      ),
      end = structure(
        c(
          NA_real_,
          NA_real_,
          NA_real_,
          NA_real_,
          NA_real_,
          NA_real_,
          NA_real_,
          NA_real_
        ),
        class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"),
        tzone = ""
      ),
      altitude_mode = c(
        NA_character_,
        NA_character_,
        NA_character_,
        NA_character_,
        NA_character_,
        NA_character_,
        NA_character_,
        NA_character_
      ),
      tessellate = c(
        1L, -1L, -1L, -1L,
        -1L, -1L, 1L, -1L
      ),
      extrude = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L),
      visibility = c(-1L, -1L, -1L, -1L, -1L, -1L, -1L, -1L),
      draw_order = c(
        NA_integer_,
        NA_integer_,
        NA_integer_,
        NA_integer_,
        NA_integer_,
        NA_integer_,
        NA_integer_,
        NA_integer_
      ),
      icon = c(
        NA_character_,
        NA_character_,
        NA_character_,
        NA_character_,
        NA_character_,
        NA_character_,
        NA_character_,
        NA_character_
      ),
      geometry = structure(
        list(
          structure(
            c(
              -213231.809501996,
              -205487.607705256,
              -784028.913066238,
              -708301.049327739
            ),
            .Dim = c(
              2L,
              2L
            ),
            class = c("XY", "LINESTRING", "sfg")
          ),
          structure(
            c(
              -213529.323058115,
              -785232.982945769
            ),
            class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")
          ),
          structure(
            c(
              -212176.423266777,
              -773238.391709674
            ),
            class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")
          ),
          structure(
            c(
              -210268.431741568,
              -756818.73172344
            ),
            class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")
          ),
          structure(
            c(
              -208050.517190725,
              -737973.862632309
            ),
            class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")
          ),
          structure(
            c(
              -206040.836893304,
              -709783.744787448
            ),
            class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")
          ),
          structure(
            c(
              -204426.676405507,
              -160265.400475699,
              -708310.127055397,
              -727750.877479657
            ),
            .Dim = c(
              2L,
              2L
            ),
            class = c("XY", "LINESTRING", "sfg")
          ),
          structure(
            c(
              -179260.597288432,
              -718361.477655825
            ),
            class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")
          )
        ),
        n_empty = 0L,
        crs = structure(
          list(input = "EPSG:3411", wkt = "PROJCRS[\"NSIDC Sea Ice Polar Stereographic North\",\n    BASEGEOGCRS[\"Unspecified datum based upon the Hughes 1980 ellipsoid\",\n        DATUM[\"Not specified (based on Hughes 1980 ellipsoid)\",\n            ELLIPSOID[\"Hughes 1980\",6378273,298.279411123064,\n                LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1]]],\n        PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\",0,\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433]],\n        ID[\"EPSG\",4054]],\n    CONVERSION[\"US NSIDC Sea Ice polar stereographic north\",\n        METHOD[\"Polar Stereographic (variant B)\",\n            ID[\"EPSG\",9829]],\n        PARAMETER[\"Latitude of standard parallel\",70,\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8832]],\n        PARAMETER[\"Longitude of origin\",-45,\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8833]],\n        PARAMETER[\"False easting\",0,\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8806]],\n        PARAMETER[\"False northing\",0,\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8807]]],\n    CS[Cartesian,2],\n        AXIS[\"easting (X)\",south,\n            MERIDIAN[45,\n                ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433]],\n            ORDER[1],\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1]],\n        AXIS[\"northing (Y)\",south,\n            MERIDIAN[135,\n                ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433]],\n            ORDER[2],\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1]],\n    USAGE[\n        SCOPE[\"unknown\"],\n        AREA[\"World - N hemisphere - north of 60°N\"],\n        BBOX[60,-180,90,180]],\n    ID[\"EPSG\",3411]]"),
          class = "crs"
        ),
        class = c(
          "sfc_GEOMETRY",
          "sfc"
        ),
        precision = 0,
        bbox = structure(
          c(
            xmin = -213529.323058115,
            ymin = -785232.982945769,
            xmax = -160265.400475699,
            ymax = -708301.049327739
          ),
          class = "bbox"
        ),
        classes = c(
          "LINESTRING",
          "POINT",
          "POINT",
          "POINT",
          "POINT",
          "POINT",
          "LINESTRING",
          "POINT"
        )
      )
    ),
    row.names = c(
      NA,
      8L
    ),
    sf_column = "geometry",
    agr = structure(
      c(
        name = NA_integer_,
        description = NA_integer_,
        timestamp = NA_integer_,
        begin = NA_integer_,
        end = NA_integer_,
        altitude_mode = NA_integer_,
        tessellate = NA_integer_,
        extrude = NA_integer_,
        visibility = NA_integer_,
        draw_order = NA_integer_,
        icon = NA_integer_
      ),
      class = "factor",
      .Label = c(
        "constant",
        "aggregate", "identity"
      )
    ),
    class = c("sf", "data.frame")
  )

dat
#> Simple feature collection with 8 features and 11 fields
#> Geometry type: GEOMETRY
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: -213529.3 ymin: -785233 xmax: -160265.4 ymax: -708301
#> Projected CRS: NSIDC Sea Ice Polar Stereographic North
#>            name description timestamp begin  end altitude_mode tessellate
#> 1 Untitled Path        <NA>      <NA>  <NA> <NA>          <NA>          1
#> 2         St34B        <NA>      <NA>  <NA> <NA>          <NA>         -1
#> 3         St35N        <NA>      <NA>  <NA> <NA>          <NA>         -1
#> 4         St36F        <NA>      <NA>  <NA> <NA>          <NA>         -1
#> 5         St37N        <NA>      <NA>  <NA> <NA>          <NA>         -1
#> 6         St38B        <NA>      <NA>  <NA> <NA>          <NA>         -1
#> 7 Untitled Path        <NA>      <NA>  <NA> <NA>          <NA>          1
#> 8         St39N        <NA>      <NA>  <NA> <NA>          <NA>         -1
#>   extrude visibility draw_order icon                       geometry
#> 1       0         -1         NA <NA> LINESTRING (-213231.8 -7840...
#> 2       0         -1         NA <NA>      POINT (-213529.3 -785233)
#> 3       0         -1         NA <NA>    POINT (-212176.4 -773238.4)
#> 4       0         -1         NA <NA>    POINT (-210268.4 -756818.7)
#> 5       0         -1         NA <NA>    POINT (-208050.5 -737973.9)
#> 6       0         -1         NA <NA>    POINT (-206040.8 -709783.7)
#> 7       0         -1         NA <NA> LINESTRING (-204426.7 -7083...
#> 8       0         -1         NA <NA>    POINT (-179260.6 -718361.5)

ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = dat) +
  geom_sf_text(
    data = dat,
    aes(label = name),
    size = 3,
    hjust = 0
  )
```

[image]

I would like to calculate the distance between stations 34 - 35 - … - 39
but along the path (station numbers determine the order).The first problems
I see is that the lines (paths) are not connected and the stations are not
connected to the lines.
I first tried to extract the paths and the stations:

```r
stations <- dat %>%
  filter(str_starts(name, "St"))

paths <- dat %>%
  filter(str_starts(name, "Untitled"))

ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = paths, color = "red") +
  geom_sf(data = stations, color = "blue") +
  geom_sf_text(
    data = stations,
    aes(label = name),
    color = "blue",
    size = 3,
    hjust = 0
  )
```

[image]

I am stuck on the next steps. I first tried to merge the lines and then
snap the points to the closest line using `st_snap()` without success. Any
help is appreciated.

<sup>Created on 2021-12-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Hi! As a starting point, I think you may want to check the R package [sfnetworks](https://luukvdmeer.github.io/sfnetworks/). Just one question: how would you estimate the distance between 38 and 39? It looks like they are not connected.

Comment: Thank you for the R package. I think the first thing to do would be to connect the lines and then snap the points to the closest line.

Comment: Would you accept a "manual" approach to connect those lines? I'm not sure how to programmatically fill the missing lines for a generic set of lines.

Answer (score 5):

Please find a detailed reprex that provides a solution to your request using the `sf`, `sfnetworks`, `units`, `dplyr` and `ggplot2` libraries.

**Reprex**

- **STEP 1: Create a 'sfnetworks' object only based 'on connected lines(i.e.edges)**

```r
library(sf)
library(units)
library(sfnetworks)
options(sfn_max_print_active = 15, sfn_max_print_inactive = 15)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

network <- dat %>% 
  filter(st_geometry_type(.) == "LINESTRING") %>%   # selects only the lines from 'sf' object 'dat'
  st_snap(.,., tolerance = 10000) %>%   # coerces the snapping using a big tolerance value!
  as_sfnetwork()  # creates the network

autoplot(network)
```

[image]

- **STEP 2: Create a 'sf' object with only points (i.e. nodes)**

```r
nodes <- dat %>% 
  filter(st_geometry_type(.) == "POINT")

nodes
#> Simple feature collection with 6 features and 11 fields
#> Geometry type: POINT
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: -213529.3 ymin: -785233 xmax: -179260.6 ymax: -709783.7
#> Projected CRS: NSIDC Sea Ice Polar Stereographic North
#>    name description timestamp begin  end altitude_mode tessellate extrude
#> 1 St34B        <NA>      <NA>  <NA> <NA>          <NA>         -1       0
#> 2 St35N        <NA>      <NA>  <NA> <NA>          <NA>         -1       0
#> 3 St36F        <NA>      <NA>  <NA> <NA>          <NA>         -1       0
#> 4 St37N        <NA>      <NA>  <NA> <NA>          <NA>         -1       0
#> 5 St38B        <NA>      <NA>  <NA> <NA>          <NA>         -1       0
#> 6 St39N        <NA>      <NA>  <NA> <NA>          <NA>         -1       0
#>   visibility draw_order icon                    geometry
#> 1         -1         NA <NA>   POINT (-213529.3 -785233)
#> 2         -1         NA <NA> POINT (-212176.4 -773238.4)
#> 3         -1         NA <NA> POINT (-210268.4 -756818.7)
#> 4         -1         NA <NA> POINT (-208050.5 -737973.9)
#> 5         -1         NA <NA> POINT (-206040.8 -709783.7)
#> 6         -1         NA <NA> POINT (-179260.6 -718361.5)
```

**STEP 3: Add the nodes of the 'sf' object into the 'network'**

*1. Code*

```r
new_network <- network %>% 
  st_network_blend(., nodes, tolerance = 10000) %>%  # snap the nodes on the network based on the given tolerance
  filter(.,!is.na(name)) %>%       # keeps only the nodes from the 'sf' object 'nodes'
  st_as_sf %>%                 # convert into sf object (mandatory step for the next one to work properly)
  as_sfnetwork(., edges_as_lines = TRUE)    # reconstructs the network only with the nodes from the 'sf' object 'nodes'
#> Warning: st_network_blend assumes attributes are constant over geometries
```

*2. Specifications of the network*

```r
new_network
#> # A sfnetwork with 6 nodes and 5 edges
#> #
#> # CRS:  EPSG:3411 
#> #
#> # A rooted tree with spatially explicit edges
#> #
#> # Node Data:     6 x 12 (active)
#> # Geometry type: POINT
#> # Dimension:     XY
#> # Bounding box:  xmin: -213231.8 ymin: -784028.9 xmax: -179639.4 ymax:
#> #   -709824.4
#>   name  description timestamp           begin               end                
#>   <chr> <chr>       <dttm>              <dttm>              <dttm>             
#> 1 St34B <NA>        NA                  NA                  NA                 
#> 2 St35N <NA>        NA                  NA                  NA                 
#> 3 St36F <NA>        NA                  NA                  NA                 
#> 4 St37N <NA>        NA                  NA                  NA                 
#> 5 St38B <NA>        NA                  NA                  NA                 
#> 6 St39N <NA>        NA                  NA                  NA                 
#> # ... with 7 more variables: altitude_mode <chr>, tessellate <int>,
#> #   extrude <int>, visibility <int>, draw_order <int>, icon <chr>,
#> #   geometry <POINT [m]>
#> #
#> # Edge Data:     5 x 3
#> # Geometry type: LINESTRING
#> # Dimension:     XY
#> # Bounding box:  xmin: -213231.8 ymin: -784028.9 xmax: -179639.4 ymax:
#> #   -709824.4
#>    from    to                                   geometry
#>   <int> <int>                           <LINESTRING [m]>
#> 1     1     2 (-213231.8 -784028.9, -212128.8 -773243.3)
#> 2     2     3 (-212128.8 -773243.3, -210447.3 -756800.4)
#> 3     3     4 (-210447.3 -756800.4, -208517.2 -737926.1)
#> 4     4     5 (-208517.2 -737926.1, -205643.4 -709824.4)
#> 5     5     6   (-205643.4 -709824.4, -179639.4 -719222)
```

*3. Visualization of the network*

```r
# option 1 with autoplot:
autoplot(new_network) +
  geom_sf_text(
        data = st_as_sf(new_network),
        aes(label = name),
        size = 3,
        hjust = 0
      )
```

[image]

```r
# if you prefer, option 2 with only ggplot:
ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = st_as_sf(new_network, "edges"), col = "grey50") +
  geom_sf(data = st_as_sf(new_network, "nodes")) +
  geom_sf_text(
    data = st_as_sf(new_network),
    aes(label = name),
    size = 3,
    hjust = 0
  )
```

[image]

- **STEP 4: Computes the length of edges between each node along the network and creates the dataframe `distances` (i.e. tibble class)**

```r
distances <- new_network %>% 
  activate("edges") %>% 
  mutate(length = set_units(edge_length(),km)) %>% 
  st_as_sf() %>% 
  st_drop_geometry

distances
#> # A tibble: 5 x 3
#>    from    to length
#> * <int> <int>   [km]
#> 1     1     2   10.8
#> 2     2     3   16.5
#> 3     3     4   19.0
#> 4     4     5   28.2
#> 5     5     6   27.6
```

- **STEP 5: Replace ids of columns "from" and "to" of the `distances` dataframe by the names of nodes**

*1. Extract names of nodes and map them to the id's of distances dataframe*

```r
names_id <- new_network %>% 
  activate("nodes") %>% 
  st_as_sf() %>% 
  mutate(ID = seq(name)) %>%
  select(., c("ID", "name")) %>% 
  st_drop_geometry

names_id
#> # A tibble: 6 x 2
#>      ID name 
#> * <int> <chr>
#> 1     1 St34B
#> 2     2 St35N
#> 3     3 St36F
#> 4     4 St37N
#> 5     5 St38B
#> 6     6 St39N
```

*2. Modify the dataframe `distances` to get the names of nodes in 'from' and 'to' columns using two `left_join()`*

```r
distances <- left_join(distances, names_id, by = c("from" = "ID")) %>% 
  mutate(from = name) %>% 
  select(-name) %>% 
  left_join(., names_id, by = c("to" = "ID")) %>% 
  mutate(to = name) %>% 
  select(-name)
```

*3. Final output*

```r
distances
#> # A tibble: 5 x 3
#>   from  to    length
#>   <chr> <chr>   [km]
#> 1 St34B St35N   10.8
#> 2 St35N St36F   16.5
#> 3 St36F St37N   19.0
#> 4 St37N St38B   28.2
#> 5 St38B St39N   27.6
```

<sup>Created on 2021-12-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Perfect. Thank you.

Comment: Glad that I could help you. Cheers.